# Why is my BigQuery query returning additional dates other than what I have specified in the WHERE clause?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the query below. I only want it to return dates as specified in the WHERE clause, however it is returning all data. I have already tried using `_TABLE_SUFFIX as date` and that did not work. What else can I do?

```
SELECT
  date,
  'iOS' as app_source,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(1) events,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) uniqueEvents
FROM
   `XXXX1.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  and date >= "20190818"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3

UNION ALL

SELECT
  date,
  'Android' as app_source,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(1) events,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitstarttime AS string))) uniqueEvents
FROM
   `XXXX2.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  and date >= "20190818"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3

ORDER BY
  date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your WHERE clause as in below example

```
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (
    (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
    or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  )
  and date >= "20190818"
```